# The operation couldn’t be completed. (MCMailErrorDomain error 1045.)

Tags: iphone, mail.app, email

I'm experiencing an issue sending out email using `Mail.app` on my `MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2013)` running `OS X Yosemite 10.10.2 (14C94b)`.

... shortly after hitting "Send message" button, I'm receiving following error:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (MCMailErrorDomain error 1045.)
```

I have *NO* problem sending out email from my iPhone 6, using same settings and from same network and I am able to connect to remote smtp server via `Terminal.app` as well.

I rechecked my `username`, `password` and the rest of the settings *MULTIPLE* times and not really sure what else to do...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in Mail / OS X 10.10.2.

After long searches for an answer, **I solved the problem simply inserting again my passoword for the SMTP account**.

Even though the stored password was correct, it didn't work until I inserted again the password. Go figure why it didn't work before !!

Comment: And by the way, can anyone explain me what exactly "MCMailErrorDomain error 1045" mean? Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Updating to El Capitan, I had this same problem. When I checked my mail settings I noticed that my incoming port was changed to 143 from 993. I changed it back to 993 and turned on SSL and all worked again.